# bcryp.hash makes nodejs stop

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

Node.js stops the execution when I call bcrypt.hash . It works flawless if I use bcrypt.hashSync.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');    
var methods = {};

methods.encryptPassword = function(password, callback){
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            callback(hash)
        } 
    });
}
module.exports = methods;
```

On another code file:

```
var methods = require('./securityMethods');
setInterval(function(){
    console.log('Im still here.')
    methods.encryptPassword('AA',function(hash){
        console.log(hash);
    })
},2000)
```

The callback function never gets called and the node process stops when it hits the bcrypt.hash function.

Expected behaviour should be the hash output in console every 2 seconds.

Comment: It will only halt when an error occurs, because you are not calling the callback in error case.

Comment: The code inside the encryptPassword function never gets executed at all.

Comment: What is the output that you get?

Comment: @Tiburoncito Your code works well on my machine. Do you've any additional code other than the one posted here?

Comment: Someone posted a comment a few hours ago but it seems it was deleted. Problem was caused by nodejs version. After updating my windows machine with the latest msi, i no longer face this behaviour and the code executes successfuly.